# Eclipse "String variable can not be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java

Here is the code, There is no way str2Check is out of scope.

```
public static void regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check)
    {
        //defining the regex pattern

        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);

        // Creating a Matcher object that searches the string for anything that
        //matches the REGEX

        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check); //error here

        while (regexMatcher.find())
        {   
            System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
            System.out.println("Start Index: " + regexMatcher.start());
            System.out.println("End Index: " +  regexMatcher.end());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String longString = " Derek Banas CA 12345 PA (412)555-1212 johnsmith@hotmail.com 412-555-1234 412 555-1234 "; 
        String strangeString = " 1Z aaa **** *** {{{ {{ { ";

        regexChecker("\\s[A-Za-z]{2,20}",longString);

    }
```

Please help out. Being scratching my head....Can't able to comprehend it at all.

Comment: your code compiles just fine. Check your eclipse settings, like jdk, compiler, etc

Comment: there has to be anything else as just like @DeiAndrei said, it works perfectly fine. maybe post the whole stacktrace or the whole code

Comment: your code works perfectly, see here https://ideone.com/Bh7aH6

Comment: make sure you saved your file, eclipse doesn't always notice that errors are gone when the file isn't saved

Comment: @5tingr4y Just saw the * sign on my java file tab. So STUPID of me!